# Looking To Combine 2 Bar Charts

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have 2 individual bar charts that I am looking to try and combine, but cant seem to tie them together

```
combinedPassengerSimulation['StartStation'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar', color="Green")
combinedPassengerSimulation['EndStation'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar', color="Blue")
```

These lines work perfectly when executed separately, but I really want to be able to combine them together, ideally showing the crossover with arriving and departing passengers at stations 2 and 3

Any help greatly appreciated[image]

Comment: Do you mind to explain the expected output?

Comment: Hi @ribena1980 do you mind to check if my answer was useful?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can follow this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
n = 100_000
df = pd.DataFrame({"StartStation":np.random.choice([1]*10+[2]*5+[3]*2, n),
                   "EndStation":np.random.choice([2]*4+[3]*7+[4]*2, n)})

# here you can use aggregate
out = df.agg({"StartStation": "value_counts",
              "EndStation": "value_counts"})
```

## Plotly

```py
fig = go.Figure()
for col in out.columns:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(x=out.index,
               y=out[col],
               name=col))
fig.show()
```

[image]

## Pandas/matplotlib

```py
out.plot(kind='bar');
```

[image]